# how to make a specific array of object from an object in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object like this. The length of value can be any number. if I add one more object in parent.info.value it will add the three more object in the expected result like this

```
{label: 'Parent Info 3', value: '2022-08-05'}
{label: 'edate 3', value: '2022-08-12'}
{label: 'xdate 3', value: '2022-08-16'}
```

I want to map

1. label with parent.info.label. depending on the length of parent.info.value. It should add number to the label. in this case the length of parent.info.value is 2 then the label should be Parent Info 1 and Parent Info 2.

edate and xdate should be mapped to parent.edate.label and parent.xdate.label. depending on the length of parent.info.value or parent.eDate.value or parent.xDate.value. It should add number to the label. in this case the length of parent.eDate.value is 2 then the label should be eDate 1 and eDate2. same for xDate the label should be xDate 1 and xDate 2.

2. value should be mapped with parent.info.value.class. It is array of object with length 2. the class value can be assigned to both the labels, parent.eDate.value has 2 array values that can be assigned to both eDate label that is eDate 1 and eDate 2,
   parent.xDate.value has 2 array values that can be assigned to both eDate label that is xDate 1 and xDate 2

Please help i tried multiple ways didn't get the desired output.

```
"parent": {
    "info": {
        "path": "parent-info",
        "label": "Parent Info",
        "value": [
            {
                "rowIndex": 0,
                "class": "Y",
                "classPath": "parent-info",
               
            },
            {
                "rowIndex": 1,
                "class": "N",
                "classPath": "parent-drugAltInfo",
                
            }
        ],
       
    },


    "edate": {
        "path": "parent-edate",
        "label": "eDate",
        "value": [
            "2022-08-04",
            "2022-08-12"
        ],
    },
    "xdate": {
        "path": "parent-xdate",
        "label": "xDate",
        "value": [
            "2022-08-05",
            "2022-08-16"
        ],
    }
}
```

I want to achive this:

```
[
    {label: 'Parent Info 1', value: 'Y'}
    {label: 'edate 1', value: '2022-08-04'}
    {label: 'xdate 1', value: 'N'}
    {label: 'Parent Info 2', value: '2022-08-05'}
    {label: 'edate 2', value: '2022-08-12'}
    {label: 'xdate 2', value: '2022-08-16'}
]
```

Comment: and the _value_ property could be only **array of strings** or **array of number**? or anything else?

Comment: Can you be more prices, what should map to label what should map to value? I cant figure it out from your example.

Comment: @MladenMilosavljevic I have added the description please let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: @MladenMilosavljevic parent.info.label, parent.eDate.label, parent.xDate.label are label and parent.info.value.class, parent.eDate.value, parent.xDate.value are value.

Comment: @ArijitMaiti label and value both the properties are string